# Mostrar Producto en Modal (PHP)

Tags: php, html, modal

Buen día ,

Estoy intentando hacer que al momento de seleccionar un producto se abra la ventana modal y me aparezca el producto seleccionado , pero no logro traer el id_codigo para que detecte que producto seleccionó.

Explico un poco de como funciona actualmente:
El producto se muestra en el inicio, seleccionas el que te gustaría comprar, se abre la ventana modal pero no detectá el producto .
Lo que busco es que muestre el producto seleccionado , de igual manera se muestre el precio y pueda seleccionar la opcíon de comprar.

Podrían comentarme cómo podría hacerlo? .
Gracias

```
<?php
 session_start();
 if(isset($_SESSION['nombre'])) echo $_SESSION['nombre'];
 include('php/conexion.php');
 $registros1=mysqli_query($conexion,"select * from categorias order by categoria asc");
 $registros2=mysqli_query($conexion,"select id_producto, precio,id_categoria,id_subcategoria,cantidad from productos where inicio=1 AND cantidad!=-2 limit 0,12");
 

//DETALLE PRODUCTO

$registros4=mysqli_query($conexion,"select nombre from imagenes where id_producto='$_GET[id_producto]' && prioridad=1"); 
$fila4=mysqli_fetch_array($registros4);
$registros5=mysqli_query($conexion,"select nombre from imagenes where id_producto='$_GET[id_producto]' && prioridad=2"); 
$fila5=mysqli_fetch_array($registros5);
$registros6=mysqli_query($conexion,"select nombre from imagenes where id_producto='$_GET[id_producto]' && prioridad=3"); 
$fila6=mysqli_fetch_array($registros6);



?>


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="script.js"></script>
   <!-- click drecho -->
   <script type='text/javascript'>
    document.oncontextmenu = function(){return false}
</script>


<!-- PRODUCTOS-->


<script src="lib/sweet-alert.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/sweet-alert.css">
<!--Ya-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalizar.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/hover-min.css">
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ceviche+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="iconos/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<!-- comentarios -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="comentarios/estilos_comentarios.css">
<!--comentario -->

<!-- --------------------------- stock -------------------------- -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/6.6.4/sweetalert2.css">
<!-- --------------------------- stock -------------------------- -->

<style>
.ui-effects-transfer { 
border: 3px #666666 solid;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
background-image:url(administracion/productos/imagenes/<?php if(mysqli_num_rows($registros4)>0)echo $fila4['nombre']; else echo "no-disponible.jpg"; ?>);
opacity:0.8;
}

.numero_carrito{
position:absolute; width:30px; height:30px; background-color: #FFF; border-radius:100%; margin-top:81px; margin-left:-41px; border: solid 2px #FF3366; text-align:center; color: #F00; font-weight:bold; padding:2.5px; font-size:14px; 
}

</style>

<!-- bootstrap -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="javascript/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- bootstrap -->

<!-- Empieza LightBox  -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="lightbox/vlb_files1/vlightbox1.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="lightbox/vlb_files1/visuallightbox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script src="lightbox/vlb_engine/visuallightbox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="lightbox/vlb_engine/vlbdata1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- Termina LightBox -->

<!-- comentarios -->
<!-- Start VideoLightBox.com HEAD section -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="comentarios/index_videolb/videolightbox.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="comentarios/index_videolb/overlay-minimal.css"/>
<script src="comentarios/index_videolb/swfobject.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- End VideoLightBox.com HEAD section -->
<!-- comentarios -->

<script type="text/javascript">

function mostrar(){

 $("#texto").show("slow");  
 $("#b_mostrar").hide("fast");
 $("#b_ocultar").show("fast");  

}

function ocultar(){

 $("#texto").hide("slow");  
 $("#b_mostrar").show("fast");
 $("#b_ocultar").hide("fast");  

}

</script>

 
<!--TERMINA--->



<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>INICIO</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="iconos/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalizar.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/hover-min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css">
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ceviche+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
<!-- bootstrap -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="javascript/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/sweet-alert.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/sweet-alert.css">

<!-- bootstrap -->

<!--Registrar-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />  
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
      <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="assets/css/sticky-footer-navbar.css" rel="stylesheet">


<script src="css/wow.min.js"></script>
<script>new WOW().init()</script>
<!--MENU-->
<!-- Start css3menu.com HEAD section -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS3 Menu_files/css3menu1/style.css" type="text/css" /><style type="text/css">._css3m{display:none}</style>
<!-- End css3menu.com HEAD section -->
    <!--BANNER-->
<!-- Start WOWSlider.com HEAD section --> <!-- add to the <head> of your page -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="engine1/style.css" />
<!-- End WOWSlider.com HEAD section -->
</head>
<body>


<header>

  <br>
    <div class="main" style=" width:100%;">
    <?php
    while($fila2=mysqli_fetch_array($registros2)){
      $registros3=mysqli_query($conexion,"select nombre from imagenes where id_producto='$fila2[id_producto]' and prioridad=1");
        $fila3=mysqli_fetch_array($registros3);

    ?>
    <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#add_data_Modal2">  <?php   $fila2['id_producto']; ?> <div id="i" class="productosmain hvr-buzz-out"><img src="administracion/productos/imagenes/<?php if(mysqli_num_rows($registros3)>0)echo $fila3['nombre'];  else echo "no-disponible.jpg"; ?>" width="100%" height="150" alt="imagen"><div class="precio"><?php echo "$".$fila2['precio']." MXN"; ?></div></div></a>

 <?php
    }
   cerrarconexion();
    ?>

    <!--carrito -->
    <div id="b"  class="carrito">
      <div  style=" width:50px; height:120px; float:left; padding:4px; background-color:#0052a5; border-radius:10px 0px 0px 10px; margin-left:-50px; cursor: pointer">
            
            <i style=" margin-top:33px; margin-left:200px; color:#FFF; font-size:35px" class="fa fa-shopping-basket" aria-hidden="true"></i>  
                
        </div>
        
        <!--numerito-->
        <?php 
      
      if(isset($_SESSION['cantidad_de_productos'])){
      
      ?>
        
        <div id="cantidad_de_productos" style="position:absolute; width:30px; height:30px; background-color: #FFF; border-radius:50%; margin-top:81px; margin-left:-41px; border: solid 2px #FF3366; text-align:center; color: #F00; font-weight:bold; padding:2.5px; font-size:14px;"><?php echo $_SESSION['cantidad_de_productos']; ?></div>
    
        
        <?php
      
      }
      
     
      ?>
        <!--numerito Muestra compra-->
        
        <div style="height:400px; padding:4px; overflow:auto" id="mostrar_compra">
            
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--carrito-->
       
       
       
<!--INICIA-->

<div id="add_data_Modal2" class="modal fade">
 <div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
   <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button"  class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
    <h4  class="modal-title"></h4>
     <!-- Form Name -->
     </br>
     <div>
     </div>
     </div>
     <legend>Producto</legend>
  <?php  

echo $fila2['id_producto'];

?>
   <div class="modal-body">

   <form method="post" id="insert_form" action="#">
    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-3 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-3 inputGroupContainer">
                <div class="input-group"> 
     </div>
     </div>
     </div>
```

```
                    <!-- Start css3menu.com HEAD section -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS3 Menu_files/css3menu1/style.css" type="text/css" /><style type="text/css">._css3m{display:none}</style>
<!-- End css3menu.com HEAD section -->

<div style="max-width:-10px; margin:-100px auto 10px auto; padding-left:-90px">

</div>
<?php
if($fila3["cantidad"]!=-2){
?>

</div>

<div style="margin:45px auto 0px auto; max-width:900px">
<div style="float:left; margin-right:20px">
    
    <?php
           $registros3=mysqli_query($conexion,"select nombre from imagenes where id_producto='$fila2[id_producto]' and prioridad=1");
        $fila3=mysqli_fetch_array($registros3);
  $registros4=mysqli_query($conexion,"select nombre from imagenes where id_producto='$_GET[id_producto]' && prioridad=1"); 
$fila4=mysqli_fetch_array($registros4);
$registros5=mysqli_query($conexion,"select nombre from imagenes where id_producto='$_GET[id_producto]' && prioridad=2"); 
$fila5=mysqli_fetch_array($registros5);
$registros6=mysqli_query($conexion,"select nombre from imagenes where id_producto='$_GET[id_producto]' && prioridad=3"); 
$fila6=mysqli_fetch_array($registros6);
  ?>


<div style="margin:45px auto 0px auto; max-width:900px">
<div style="float:left; margin-right:20px">
<div id="a"><a class="vlightbox1" href="administracion/productos/imagenes/>" title="<?php echo utf8_encode($fila3['nombre']); ?>"><img width="330px" height="247px" src="administracion/productos/imagenes/<?php if(mysqli_num_rows($registros4)>0)echo $fila4['nombre']; else echo "no-disponible.jpg"; ?>"/></a></div>
</br>

</div>
<p style="font-size:30px; font-family:'Helvetica', cursive;">
<?php 
echo utf8_encode($fila3['nombre'])."</p>";
if($fila3["descargable"]==1) echo "<b>Producto Digital o con contenido descargable</b>"; 
?>

<form name="formu_compra">
<!--PRECIO DEL PRUCTO-->
<span style="font-size:30px; font-family:'Helvetica', cursive; color:#3B5998"><?php echo "$".$fila3['precio']; ?> MXN &nbsp;X&nbsp;&nbsp;

<input style="width:65px; color:#333" type="number" name="cantidad_producto" min="1" max="10" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="nombre_producto" value="<?php echo utf8_encode($fila3['nombre']); ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="precio_producto" value="<?php echo $fila3['precio']; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="id_producto" value="<?php echo $_GET["id_producto"]; ?>">

<!-- ---------------- Producto descargable ---------------------- -->
<input type="hidden" name="descargable" value="<?php echo $fila3["descargable"]; ?>"> 
<!-- ---------------- Producto descargable ---------------------- -->
<!--<button type="button" onClick="volar()" class="btn btn-primary">Comprar ahora</button>-->

<!-- ----------------stock-------------------------- -->
<?php
if($fila3["cantidad"]>0 || $fila3["cantidad"]==-1){
?>
    <button type="button" onClick="comprobar_stock('<?php echo $fila3["cantidad"]; ?>')" class="btn btn-primary">Comprar ahora</button>
<?php
}else{ 

    echo "¡Agotado!";
    echo "</span>";
    
    ?>
    <div onClick="aviso_stock('<?php echo $fila3["id_producto"]; ?>')" style="color:orange;cursor:pointer">
        Avísame cuando haya stock
    </div>
    <?php
    
}
?>
<!-- ----------------stock-------------------------- -->
</span>
</form>

<!-- ----------------stock-------------------------- -->
<?php
if($fila3["cantidad"]<=10 && $fila3["cantidad"]>0){
    
    echo "<strong><span style='color:orange'>¡ Quedan solo ".$fila3["cantidad"]." unidades !</span></strong>";
}
?>
<!-- ----------------stock-------------------------- -->


<p style="font-size:25px; font-family:'Helvetica', cursive;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;* Características:</p>
<div>
<?php
$array=explode(" ",utf8_encode($fila3['descripcion']));

if(count($array)<35){
    
    for($i=0;$i<count($array);$i++){
    
        echo $array[$i]." ";
    
    }
    
}

else{
    
    for($i=0;$i<35;$i++){
    
        echo $array[$i]." ";
    
        }
    echo "...";
 ?>
    </div>
    <div id="texto" style="display:none">
    <?php
    for($i=35;$i<count($array);$i++){
    
        echo $array[$i]." ";
    
        }

    ?>
</div>
</br>

<?php
}
 ?>

<!-- comentarios -->
<?php 
include("comentarios/index_comentarios.php");
?>
<!-- comentarios -->

</div>
</div>
<?php
cerrarconexion();
?>

<div class="limpiar"></div>

</div>



<?php
}
?>

    <?php 
    
    if(isset($_SESSION['cantidad_de_productos'])){
    
    ?>
    
    <div id="cantidad_de_productos" style="position:absolute; width:30px; height:30px; background-color: #FFF; border-radius:100%; margin-top:81px; margin-left:-41px; border: solid 2px #FF3366; text-align:center; color: #F00; font-weight:bold; padding:2.5px; font-size:14px;"><?php echo $_SESSION['cantidad_de_productos']; ?></div>

    
    <?php
    
    }
    
    else {
    ?>
    
    <div id="cantidad_de_productos"><?php if(isset($_SESSION['cantidad_de_productos'])){ echo $_SESSION['cantidad_de_productos']; } ?></div>
    
    <?php
    }
    
    ?>
    <!--numerito TamaÃ±o d-->
    
    <div style="height:400px; padding:4px; overflow:auto" id="mostrar_compra">
        
    </div>
</div>
<!--carrito-->
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
     <br />
 


<script type="text/javascript" src="clientes/inicio_de_sesion/inicio_de_sesion.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="compra/compra.js"></script>
<!-- comentarios -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="comentarios/comentarios.js"></script>
<!-- comentarios -->

<!-- --------------------------- stock -------------------------- -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/6.6.4/sweetalert2.js"></script>
<!-- --------------------------- stock -------------------------- -->



    
    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="clientes/inicio_de_sesion/inicio_de_sesion.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="compra/compra.js"></script>
    <script src="proceso_compra.js"></script>
   
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="clientes/registro_clientes.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>


    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hola dice que quieres pasar solo el id del producto al modal bueno yo lo haría así

Primero haría include a la modal después recorro el listado de productos y su codigo,titulo, etc lo almaceno en un data.

```
<?php include("modal_producto.php"); ?>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" 
data-target="#MODALPRODUCTO"
data-codigo_producto="<?php echo $datos_consulta["codigo"]; ?>"
data-codigo_titulo="<?php echo $datos_consulta["titulo"]; ?>">Seleccionar
</button>
```

En el JS llamas al modal por su id y pasas las variables del data.

```
$('#MODALPRODUCTO').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
    var button = $(event.relatedTarget)
    var codigo_expediente= button.data('codigo_expediente')
    var codigo_titulo = button.data('codigo_titulo')
    $('#codigo_expediente').val(codigo_expediente)
    $('#codigo_titulo').val(codigo_titulo)
})
```

En la venta modal muestras los datos almacenados del data en los id del los input ahí lo puede dar estilo a los input o es depende cada uno.

```
<div id="MODALPRODUCTO" class="modal fade" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">>
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
        
        <div class="modal-header">                      
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Producto</h4>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal"">
CERRAR
</button>

                    </div>
                    <div class="venta-modal-tramite">
<input type="text" name="codigo_producto" id="codigo_producto" >
<input type="text" name="codigo_titulo" id="codigo_titulo" >
            
                    </div>
                    
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Espero haberte ayudado. Saludos.